# jQuery exclude elements with certain class in selector

Tags: jquery

I want to setup a click event trigger in jQuery for certain anchor tags.

I want to open certain links in a new tab while ignoring ones with a certain class (before you ask I cannot put classes on the links I am trying to catch as they come from a CMS).

I want to exclude links with class **`"button"`** OR **`"generic_link"`**

I have tried:

```
$(".content_box a[class!=button]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work, also how do I do an OR statement to include **`"generic_link"`** in the exclusion?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

You can use the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$(".content_box a").not(".button")
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$(".content_box a:not('.button')")
```

There is little difference between the two approaches, except `.not()` is more readable (especially when chained) and `:not()` is very marginally faster. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8845863/1025702) for more info on the differences.

Comment: So I could do:

$(".content_box a").not(".button").not(".generic_link").click(function (e)...?

Comment: Worked perfectly, even when using `.each()`.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug when using `.text()` - the text of the element removed using say `.not` is still in the text.

Answer (score 29):

use this..

`$(".content_box a:not('.button')")`

Answer (score 4):

To add some info that helped me today, a jQuery object/`this` can also be passed in to the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navitem").click(function(){
        $(".navitem").removeClass("active");
        $(".navitem").not($(this)).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.navitem
{
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.navitem.active
{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navitem">Home</div>
<div class="navitem">About</div>
<div class="navitem">Pricing</div>
```

The above example can be simplified, but wanted to show the usage of `this` in the `not()` selector.