# Conditional jQuery on element style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use some jQuery code to modify style of an H1 element like this:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {            
  $('h1').css('text-transform', 'lowercase');
});
```

but I want to exclude some element with a precise class of that, so I try to change my code this way, with no results:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  //Changer la casse des titres H1 qui sont en Majuscules
  if ($('h1').hasClass('.vdl_titre')) {
    $('h1').css('text-transform', 'inherit');
  } else {
    $('h1').css('text-transform', 'lowercase');
  }
});
```

So help is needed :)
thanks

Comment: As rightly pointer out by @[gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984039/gurvinder372), removing dot(`.`) would solve the issue. Dot represents class but in selector and there can be different combinations, hence you need this identifier. `hasClass` checks for availability of class only, so it expects name as string without any identifier. Please check **[docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** before using.

Comment: *exclude some element* for this, you can use `not` selector. Try `$('h1:not(.vdl_titre)').css(...)`

Comment: Refer this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015103/jquery-exclude-elements-with-certain-class-in-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use has class like this:

```
hasClass("vdl_titre")
```