# .load() whole page to modal and .remove() specific div from it at the same time with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need to exclude some divs (one or several) from the page that I .load() from the same domain to modal, I use this to load pages:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#div-id-where-to-load-page").load("loaded-page-url");});
```

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#div-id-where-to-load-page").load("loaded-page-url").remove(#div-id-to-remove);});
```

and its not working, if I break it to separate functions it doesn't work either, I am new to JS, what am I doing wrong?

All scripts are loaded from the separate file (if it is important).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015103/jquery-exclude-elements-with-certain-class-in-selector
this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a callback function on the `.load()` method. This way you guarantee that the elements you want to remove are already loaded to the DOM when you call the `.remove()`.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#div-id-where-to-load-page")
        .load("loaded-page-url", function() {
            $('#div-id-to-remove').remove();
        });
});
```

Comment: What If I want to exclude several divs, I just add this line " $('#div-id-to-remove').remove(); " again? Thank You, it works like a charm! @Pedro Henrique

Comment: You can call once for each element you want to remove, but `.remove()` will also work on a list of elements, something like this `$('p').remove();` will remove all the paragraphs.